# Mahout returning same results in sequentials runs

Tags: java, eclipse, mahout, collaborative-filtering

I'm trying an Apache Mahout example using the code bellow. Everything works fine except that each time I change the userId value I need to run the class twice so that new values are returned. What I mean by that, is that every time I run it, the previous run output is showed, even with a different userId and that user recommendations.

I've tried not using the cache recommender but that hasn't worked either.

I'm using Eclipse IDE and the code of the class is the following:

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("database.csv"));

UserSimilarity userSimilarity = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(model);
System.out.println("Method: " + userSimilarity.getClass().getName().substring(userSimilarity.getClass().getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1));    

int neighborhood= 25;
System.out.println("Neighborhood: " + neighborhood);
UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(neighborhood, userSimilarity, model);
Recommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, userSimilarity);
Recommender cachingRecommender = new CachingRecommender(recommender);

int userId = 1234;
System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);       
List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = cachingRecommender.recommend(userId, 15);

System.out.println("Recomendations:");
for (RecommendedItem r : recommendations) {
    System.out.println(r.getItemID() + " " + r.getValue());
}
```